# Serving personalized javascript code to a client

Tags: javascript, laravel, socket.io

First of all, I've tried to look for answers in different questions and forums, but I've struggled to find the correct search keywords, so I haven't found anything relevant.

Basically, I've taken on developing a simple implementation of a live chat widget for websites, similar to [olark](https://www.olark.com/), [liveChat](https://www.livechatinc.com/), etc. Since, I will be using Socket.IO, I am looking for an easy way to provide the javascript code to a potential client (which might very well not be tech savvy). So the idea is to have just a simple `<script>` tag which either dynamically creates another script tag with the source pointing to my server, or just a script tag with the correct source.

The problem I have is regarding the server response to that request. In the test implementation, I am adding a script tag which makes a call to the server and the server responds with the javascript code in a string, which I find a very crude way to do it. The reason why I can't just serve a simple javascript file is, because it needs to be personalized, so I can keep track of where the client is connecting from in order to get the to the proper "agent" (manager of website). I could probably create separate files for each user, but I am not sure how maintainable and efficient that would be.

**So my question is, how would I serve this personalized javascript code in an efficient and secure way?** I am using Laravel as a backend, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What exactly is the degree of personalization of the javascript you serve? Is it just some variables that get different values for different users?

Comment: Yes, just some tokens and request keys. But ideally, I would like to be able to change the code on the client's website if something comes up(update of software, vulnerabilities, etc.) without them having to do any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the test implementation, I am adding a script tag which makes a call to the server and the server responds with the javascript code in a string, which I find a very crude way to do it.

If it works for your needs, this is a good solution.

If it feels crude, there are a few things which can help keep it clean.  Keep your javascript in a separate file and use `file_get_contents` to read from that file.  Where you need to use placeholders to personalize this, you can add `%s` and use `sprintf` to pop in the personalizations.

There are a few pretty large ad networks out there which are serving up javascript in just this fashion so I do not believe there is anything inherently wrong with this method.

As far as security goes, I'm not sure what you can do besides making sure everything is served via HTTPS.  I'd hope that there is no need to pass sensitive information via get variables.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the response. I hadn't thought about using `file_get_contents` and `sprintf`, which would definitely make it slightly more elegant. As for the security, I will not be sending sensitive information, so I assume HTTPS would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can transmit just the javascript without a `<script>` tag to the client and then use `eval()` to run the code there.

Comment: So, basically responding to the request with just a string of code? Because, as I said in the question, that's what i am doing now, but I feel it's quite a dirty way of doing it.

Comment: Sure it's dirty. If you don't need the flexibility it's better to pass certain parameters and use them with a fixed function that's already defined on the client side. E.g. you pass (100,150,20) and use these three values to call the function drawCircle(100,150,20) on the client.

Comment: The idea is to keep the code on the client side as simple as possible, so just something like <script src="myapi.com/chat.js"></script>, which contains the actual implementation.

Comment: Usually you'll have a fixed set of functions to choose from. Just put them in a JS file, include it and call the function you need with some kind of jump table

Comment: I didn't get that. Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: To avoid doing the insecure `eval` you could have a switch statement: `switch(command) { case "circle": circle(a,b,c); case "rectangle": rectangle(a,b,c,d); ...}`

Comment: I see. But I still don't want to add any code on the client side other than requesting the actual code from the server. This is the way the other apps that i mentioned - olark, liveChat, etc. are doing it, and I would like to figure it out as well. Sumome are doing the same thing. I will definitely not add any functionalities code on the client's side, I want to add it remotely.